# how to diplay page id for review php in div?

Tags: php, html, sql

I tried several options but they are not working, I have 2 pages, `page.php` and `rating.php`, on `page.php`, I have button with this link

`< a href=”rating.php/go.php?id=$rows[$id]”>button</a>`

, but on page `rating.php` I have a div with code.

`<div id="review" ><?php echo $rows['id'];?></div>`

I want that the `$rows[$id]`from the link `rating.php/go.php?id=$rows[$id]` could be displayed on div like this . How can I do that to see this `$rows[$id]` on div?

Comment: why do you link `rating.php\go.php`?

Answer (score 1):

On page.php you are using `< a href="rating.php?id=$rows[$id]">button</a>`

If you want `$rows[$id]` in your rating.php use $_GET

```
<div id="review" ><?php echo $_GET['id'];?></div>
```

Read this tutorials too http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm

Comment: i have made some changes on page.php , the link to review is only rating.php and on this page depending on id appears reviews for this ID (post), on page rating.php there is the code <div id="review" > <?php echo $rows['id'];?> </div>

Answer (score 0):

you get a param from an url with that code snippet:

```
<div id="review"><?php echo $_GET['id']; ?></div>
```

the `$row[$id]` must be a value, it can't be an object

Answer (score 0):

works as :

```
<div id="review"><?php echo $_GET['id']; ?></div>
```

Read this:
http://www.formget.com/php-post-get/